# macOS Sierra sshd ignores Port setting in sshd_config

Tags: macos, ssh

I use Remote Login on my MBP and before macOS Sierra had no problem configuring what port I wanted to use. I have tried to set the port in `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by uncommenting the `Port` setting so I have a line that just says `Port 12345`. After I restart the `sshd` daemon or reboot it still refuses connections on whatever port I select defaults to 22 instead.

I know that I'm editing the right `sshd_config` file and restarting properly because I can change the text shown at `ssh` login by changing the line that sets the `Banner` file.

I can work around this by configuring my router to forward the port I want to use to port 22 but I'd still like to know why this stopped working.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of OSX the port is not controlled by the `sshd_config` file but instead by the `ssh.plist` file located at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

There are several ways to customise the sshd port. Good write ups explaining how to do this can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307940/how-to-run-sshd-on-port-500-in-high-sierra) and [here](https://n8henrie.com/2015/10/how-to-change-the-ssh-port-on-osx-el-capitan/).